# Robot framework get file name from website source code dynamically

Tags: html, selenium, automation, backup, robotframework

So, I am trying to automate taking backups from the server. 
Using RIDE 1.5 - robot framework:
Login to the server site, generate a new backup, download the file.

Now to download the file, link needs to be clicked, and system generates the backup file name which changes everytime with new backups. I cannot change the naming scheme.

The backup file name is shown on page after backup is created.

Is there some way to select and store that name in a variable dynamically, which can be then used to download the file.

When a new backup file is created , name is shown on the page :  docs - 12 Jan 2016 612.bak

**Update:**
So I figured it out :

${backup 2} Get Text xpath=//span[@id='OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_lblMessage']

${backup 1}=    Fetch From Left ${backup 2} " created

${backup file name}=    Fetch From Right    ${backup 1} file "

Now: Is there a way to make robot click on the download OK of the browser.

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_pResponse" class="responseTable">


    <table id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_responseTable" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="150">
            <span id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_lblTitle" class="responseTitle">Completed:</span>
            </td>
            <td> <div id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_pContainer">

            <span id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_lblMessage" class="responseMessage">Backup file "docs - 12 Jan 2016 612.bak" created successfully for Database docs<BR>It has been copied to the App_data folder of the docs Domain.</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$OuterMainContent$MainContent$ResponseMessage1$hAction" id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_hAction" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$OuterMainContent$MainContent$ResponseMessage1$hParameter" id="OuterMainContent_MainContent_ResponseMessage1_hParameter" />



            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



</div>
```

Comment: Does your browser open a file dialog when you want to save this backup file? This is usually provided by OS and cannot be manipulated by Selenium. Depending on OS you are using, you might be able to manipulate this using GUI test automation. Sending ENTER might be enough. Other alternative is check if you can configure your browser to automatically save files to a location without prompting anything.

Comment: When the link is clicked, it opens a new tab/window which takes some variable time to load and then automatic switch back to main page which gives the dialog box for Save options. To use enter key, selenium/robot needs an element on which it then clicks Enter(\\13). Press Native Key function was deprecated in selenium2library.

Comment: Selenium2Library has keyword Press Key. I am using that to send enter ('\\13') to textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to downloads, Selenium is not very reliable, as it is designed to test web pages and not to do file donwloads.

You should get the URL by calling GetAttribute("href") on your download link/button WebElement and then handle the downloading outside of Selenium, if possible.